# Word 2010 automation: 'goto bookmark'

Tags: delphi, automation, ms-word, delphi-7

I have a program written in Delphi-7 which opens a new Word document which is based on a template.
Once the document is open, the automation jumps to a bookmark (predefined in the template) and adds some text there.
The following code works fine in Word 2003 but causes a `invalid variant operation` error message in Word 2010 *(I have omitted `try/except` blocks for the sake of clarity)*.

```
wrdapp:= CreateOleObject ('Word.Application');
wrdDoc:= wrdapp.documents.add (wrdApp.Options.DefaultFilePath[wdUserTemplatesPath] + '1.dot'
wrdApp.selection.goto (wdGotoBookmark, unassigned, unassigned, 'B1')
```

If I replace the third line with

```
wrdDoc.bookmarks.item ('B1').select
```

the program works fine in Word 2003 but still crashes in Word 2010.

What is the correct code for Word 2010 to 'go to' the bookmark?

Comment: Just curious, if you put a 10 second wait (`Sleep(10000);`) between the first and second line, do you still get the error?

Comment: Unbelievable but true! Make your comment an answer because the sleep is what made the code work. I cut the time to 5 seconds but that also worked.

Comment: Wait a minute... There *has* to be a better way than a fixed sleep interval. Of course, this approach may work in almost every instance, but there is probably a way that is guaranteed to work in *every* instance. One would expect something like `wrdApp.WaitUntilReady`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word 2010 has a bug that is related to loading Normal.dotm (and maybe plugins too, who knows?). When you start Word 2010 as you would normally do, you see a splashscreen and Word performs some initialization, including loading Normal.dotm. When you start Word via automation - `CreateOleObject('Word.Application')` - it doesn't wait till Normal.dotm is loaded and returns immediatly. But performing operations when Normal.dotm is still being loaded seems to crash Word. What I did to solve this problem is to make a loop that just waits for the template to load. You can also choose for a delay to give Word the time to initialize, but so far, the loop works.

Something like this:

```
wrdapp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');

//loop that waits for the normal template to load
while wrdapp.Templates.Count = 0 do
  Sleep(200);

//continue operations
```

PS: I don't have Delphi available here, so the code may contain errors, but you get the idea

Comment: Well, "a bug" is an [under](http://superuser.com/questions/274153/microsoft-word-cannot-save)[statement](http://superuser.com/questions/277425/microsoft-word-cannot-open)...

Comment: The unlooped 'sleep' works well, although I think that I will use the loop as it will probably save time. I noticed when running the corrected program that a small window popped up and closed on the screen during the sleep, but it happened so fast that I couldn't see what was written in the window. Probably something to do with templates....

Comment: @No'am Newman: indeed, the window title says something like 'Downloading'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace the constants in the "GoTo_" call with variables. Like that:

```
...
var 
  vWhat, vBookmark:OleVariant;
begin
  ...
  vWhat:=wdGoToBookmark;
  vBookmark:='B1';
  wrdApp.Selection.GoTo_(vWhat,emptyParam,emptyParam,vBookmark);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Using the variables gave this error message: "Error on going to bookmark B1 - Access violation at address 00458BCB in module 'Testword.exe'. Read of address 00000000". Incidentally, I am writing 'wrdApp.Selection.goto' and not 'wrdApp.selection.goto_' because the latter causes an error "method goto_ not supported by automation object" with Office 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope this help you. I am using D2010 and Office 2010

What I am doing: If I found a Bookmark name, I insert a word Document in this point

Part of my code:

---

```
try
  Template    := EmptyParam;
  NewTemplate := true;
  ItemIndex   := 1;
  try
     Wdapplication.Connect;
  except
     Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
     MessageDlg('No se detecta Word Puede no estar instalado(1) o versi?n incorrecta de Word', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
     Abort;
     result := False;
  end;
  Wdapplication.Visible := true; // False;
  WdApplication.Caption := 'Kalemat automation';
  {Turn Spell checking of because it takes a long time if enabled and slows down Winword}
  WdApplication.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType := false;
  WdApplication.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType := false;
  lbInfo.Lines.Add('Word connected');
except
  on E: Exception do begin
     ShowMessage(E.Message);
     WdApplication.Disconnect;
     result := False;
     Exit;
  end;
end;

//-
if wdapplication.Documents.Count > 0 then begin
  Screen.Cursor         := crDefault;
  MessageDlg(
     'Por Favor cierre todos sus Word-documentos antes de proseguir...', mtWarning,
     [mbRetry], 0);
  wdApplication.Visible := true;
  WdApplication.Disconnect;
     result := False;
  exit;
end
else begin
  with WdApplication do begin
     //      OnQuit             := WordAppQuit;
     //      OnChangeDocument   := WordDocChange;
     //      OnOpenDocument     := WordDocOpen;
     //      OnPreCloseDocument := WordPreClose;
     //      OnCloseDocument    := WordDocClose;
     //      DisableSystemCloseBox;
  end
end;
{Create new document}
Template     := EmptyParam;
NewTemplate  := false;
oNewDocument := ModEsc;

// abre documento 
lbInfo.Lines.Add('Abriendo escritura '+ModEsc);

WdApplication.Documents.AddOld(oNewDocument, NewTemplate);
// Conecta con al instancia de Word
WdDocument.ConnectTo(WdApplication.Documents.Item(ItemIndex));
sBookMarkName := 'FPROEMIO';
lbInfo.Lines.Add('Busca marcador Proemio');
if WdDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(sBookMarkName) then begin
  //     ShowMessage(' -Existe: '+sBookMarkName);
  owhat := wdGotoBookMark;
  owhich := unAssigned;
  ocount := unAssigned;
  //-->>>      //     ShowMessage(' -Ve a..: '+sBookMarkName);
  //-->>>      //   Ve a ese marcados addendum

  wdDocument.GoTo_(oWhat, oWhich, OCount, sBookMarkName);

  //     ShowMessage(' GoTo_.. ya estoy en: '+sBookMarkName);
  //   Lo encontre
  oRange       := '';
  oConformConv := false;
  oLink        := false;
  oattachment  := false;
  fl_Name      := proemi;
  lbInfo.Lines.Add('Insertando Proemio '+Proemi);
  if not FileExists(fl_name) then begin
     Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
     lbInfo.Lines.Add('No Existe Documento PROEMIO ');
     MessageDlg('Documento FPROEMIO NO EXISTE, Revise el modelo de escritura', mtError, [mbRetry], 0);
  end
  else
    wdDocument.Bookmarks.Item(sBookMarkName).Range.InsertFile(Fl_Name, oRange, oConformConv, oLink, oattachment);
  //     ShowMessage(' -.. inserte el addendum');
end
else begin
  lbInfo.Lines.Add('No Existe Marcador PROEMIO ');
end;
```